# Access a nested Array/Object - Nested Object Destructuring

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, object

i'm trying for over a week now, but it seems that i don't understand all the examples i can find online.. Somehow things don't work out for me..

I get the JSON as a response from an API and i want to access the Informations inside the ArticleList Array.
But when i try to console.log something it says **"undefined"**..
For testing purposes, i added a function that returns the JSON so i can test it without calling the API.

This is the latest version of my code:

```js
function makeArrayOfArticleList() {
   return {
      data: {
         FinalHelperCombinationList: [],
         FinalCombinationList: [
            {
               ArticleList: [
                  {
                     Id: 54,
                     Description: "VT-U 20mm/4x10-20/140(30)",
                     Number: "719241",
                     Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
                  },
                  {
                     Id: 54,
                     Description: "VT-U 20mm/4x10-20/140(30)",
                     Number: "719241",
                     Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
                  },
               ],
               TotalSize: 40,
               HighSize: 40,
               Category1: false,
               Category2: false,
               Category3: false,
               Category4: false,
               Category6: false,
               Category7: false,
               CombinationScore: 0,
            },
            {
               ArticleList: [
                  {
                     Id: 113,
                     Description: "VT-U 30mm/4x10-20/140(24)",
                     Number: "719230",
                     Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
                  },
                  {
                     Id: 114,
                     Description: "VT-U 10mm/4x10-20/140(40)",
                     Number: "719240",
                     Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
                  },
               ],
               TotalSize: 40,
               HighSize: 40,
               Category1: false,
               Category2: false,
               Category3: false,
               Category4: false,
               Category6: false,
               Category7: false,
               CombinationScore: 0,
            },
            {
               ArticleList: [
                  {
                     Id: 51,
                     Description: "VT-B 15mm/4x10-15/140, 4Stege(40)",
                     Number: "719041",
                     Datasheet: "04.05-01_vt-b.pdf",
                  },
                  {
                     Id: 51,
                     Description: "VT-B 15mm/4x10-15/140, 4Stege(40)",
                     Number: "719041",
                     Datasheet: "04.05-01_vt-b.pdf",
                  },
                  {
                     Id: 114,
                     Description: "VT-U 10mm/4x10-20/140(40)",
                     Number: "719240",
                     Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
                  },
               ],
               TotalSize: 40,
               HighSize: 40,
               Category1: false,
               Category2: false,
               Category3: false,
               Category4: false,
               Category6: false,
               Category7: false,
               CombinationScore: 0,
            },
         ],
      },
   };
}

const { FinalCombinationList: { ArticleList } } = makeArrayOfArticleList;

console.log(ArticleList);
```

I appreciate your help, thanks.

Greetings
Erik

Comment: Please may you share a [mcve] showing how you fetch the JSON data and parse it?

Comment: `FinalCombinationList` is an array of objects. Which one are you after?

Comment: Is there some reason you want to use destructing as opposed to just using dot nation to point to the nested property?

Comment: 1. You are not *calling* the function `= makeArrayOfArticleList;` should be `= makeArrayOfArticleList();` 2. the object has a `data` property you're not accessing. 3. `FinalCombinationList` is an array, it doesn't have a `ArticleList` property.

Comment: @AndresLowrie no there is no specific reason. I've tried dot nation, but i couldn't get it to work.. so i tried destructing.

Comment: The OP has to destructure/assign `FinalCombinationList` correctly in first place (and actually call the `makeArrayOfArticleList` function) ... `const { data: { FinalCombinationList } } = makeArrayOfArticleList();` ... 2nd, there are more than just a single `ArticleList` within `FinalCombinationList`. Thus said, what does the OP want `ArticleList` to be like?

Comment: @erikarens ... Regarding all the provided answers / solutions / approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

Try to destructure like this, since ArticleList is array type:

```js
const {
  data: {
    FinalCombinationList: [ArticleList],
  },
} = makeArrayOfArticleList();
```

See @VLAZ comment for further details.

Comment: Does't this just parse one ArticleList to the variable?

Comment: Comments can get deleted. If there is something relevant in one to your answer you should include that with the answer. You can still give credit to the original commenter with something like "as @VLAZ mentioned <blah blah blah>" so that all the info is together and the comment isn't required for a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't this destrucing would work here, this returns just one array of ArticleList. In the examples below map or foreach is used to get all the data.

This creates an array with the article lists combined based of the function;

With this you can add code to skip duplicates:

```
let articleList = [];
makeArrayOfArticleList().data.FinalCombinationList.forEach(e=> articleList = articleList.concat(e.ArticleList));
console.log(articleList);
```

Or just (which just outputs all articlelists combined:

```
makeArrayOfArticleList().data.FinalCombinationList.flatMap(e=> e.ArticleList);
```

Or as requested, split in array for each ArticleList

```
makeArrayOfArticleList().data.FinalCombinationList.map(e=> e.ArticleList);
```

Comment: This works, but I want to make a Table out of every ArticleList. So i need to access each ArticleList individualy. Is this possible too?
Or am i on the wrong route with the way im thinking?

Comment: `makeArrayOfArticleList().data.FinalCombinationList.map(e=> e.ArticleList);` Like this? This returns the arrays separately

Answer (score 0):

From the above comment ...

> *"The OP has to destructure/assign `FinalCombinationList` correctly in first place (and actually call the `makeArrayOfArticleList` function) ... `const { data: { FinalCombinationList } } = makeArrayOfArticleList();` ... 2nd, there are more than just a single `ArticleList` within `FinalCombinationList`. Thus said, what does the OP want `ArticleList` to be like?"*

If all the `ArticleList`s of any of a `FinalCombinationList`'s item are supposed to be aggregated/concatenated into a single array then [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is the right method to go with, whereas [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does return an array of `ArticleList`s ...

```js
const { data: { FinalCombinationList } } = makeArrayOfArticleList();

const aggregatedArticleList =
  FinalCombinationList.flatMap(({ ArticleList }) => ArticleList);

const listOfArticleLists =
  FinalCombinationList.map(({ ArticleList }) => ArticleList);

console.log({ aggregatedArticleList, listOfArticleLists });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
function makeArrayOfArticleList() {
  return {
    data: {
      FinalHelperCombinationList: [],
      FinalCombinationList: [{
        ArticleList: [{
          Id: 54,
          Description: "VT-U 20mm/4x10-20/140(30)",
          Number: "719241",
          Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
        }, {
          Id: 54,
          Description: "VT-U 20mm/4x10-20/140(30)",
          Number: "719241",
          Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
        }],
        TotalSize: 40,
        HighSize: 40,
        Category1: false,
        Category2: false,
        Category3: false,
        Category4: false,
        Category6: false,
        Category7: false,
        CombinationScore: 0,
      }, {
        ArticleList: [{
          Id: 113,
          Description: "VT-U 30mm/4x10-20/140(24)",
          Number: "719230",
          Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
        }, {
          Id: 114,
          Description: "VT-U 10mm/4x10-20/140(40)",
          Number: "719240",
          Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
        }],
        TotalSize: 40,
        HighSize: 40,
        Category1: false,
        Category2: false,
        Category3: false,
        Category4: false,
        Category6: false,
        Category7: false,
        CombinationScore: 0,
      }, {
        ArticleList: [{
          Id: 51,
          Description: "VT-B 15mm/4x10-15/140, 4Stege(40)",
          Number: "719041",
          Datasheet: "04.05-01_vt-b.pdf",
        }, {
          Id: 51,
          Description: "VT-B 15mm/4x10-15/140, 4Stege(40)",
          Number: "719041",
          Datasheet: "04.05-01_vt-b.pdf",
        }, {
          Id: 114,
          Description: "VT-U 10mm/4x10-20/140(40)",
          Number: "719240",
          Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
        }],
        TotalSize: 40,
        HighSize: 40,
        Category1: false,
        Category2: false,
        Category3: false,
        Category4: false,
        Category6: false,
        Category7: false,
        CombinationScore: 0,
      }],
    },
  };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// I have put your data into a variable; then started destructuring;
//at the end of this code you will find the data from the array ArticleList in tebular form.

const jsonResult = {
  data: {
    FinalHelperCombinationList: [],
    FinalCombinationList: [
      {
        ArticleList: [
          {
            Id: 54,
            Description: "VT-U 20mm/4x10-20/140(30)",
            Number: "719241",
            Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
          },
          {
            Id: 54,
            Description: "VT-U 20mm/4x10-20/140(30)",
            Number: "719241",
            Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
          },
        ],
        TotalSize: 40,
        HighSize: 40,
        Category1: false,
        Category2: false,
        Category3: false,
        Category4: false,
        Category6: false,
        Category7: false,
        CombinationScore: 0,
      },
      {
        ArticleList: [
          {
            Id: 113,
            Description: "VT-U 30mm/4x10-20/140(24)",
            Number: "719230",
            Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
          },
          {
            Id: 114,
            Description: "VT-U 10mm/4x10-20/140(40)",
            Number: "719240",
            Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
          },
        ],
        TotalSize: 40,
        HighSize: 40,
        Category1: false,
        Category2: false,
        Category3: false,
        Category4: false,
        Category6: false,
        Category7: false,
        CombinationScore: 0,
      },

      {
        ArticleList: [
          {
            Id: 51,
            Description: "VT-B 15mm/4x10-15/140, 4Stege(40)",
            Number: "719041",
            Datasheet: "04.05-01_vt-b.pdf",
          },
          {
            Id: 51,
            Description: "VT-B 15mm/4x10-15/140, 4Stege(40)",
            Number: "719041",
            Datasheet: "04.05-01_vt-b.pdf",
          },
          {
            Id: 114,
            Description: "VT-U 10mm/4x10-20/140(40)",
            Number: "719240",
            Datasheet: "04.06-01_vt-u.pdf",
          },
        ],
        TotalSize: 40,
        HighSize: 40,
        Category1: false,
        Category2: false,
        Category3: false,
        Category4: false,
        Category6: false,
        Category7: false,
        CombinationScore: 0,
      },
    ],
  },
};

// Starting of Destructuring

const {
  data: { FinalCombinationList: articles },
} = jsonResult;

//variable "articles" is an array containing objects as its elements.
// so applying froEach loop to the array "articles"

articles.forEach((article) => {
  // after looping through "articles" we get nested objects "article"
  // Destructuring "article" to get ArticleList. ArticleList will be  arrays.

  const { ArticleList } = article;

  //applying froEach loop to the array "ArticleList"

  ArticleList.forEach((articleInfo) => {
    // to show data in tebular format

    console.table(articleInfo);

    //"articleInfo" are objects.
    //Destructuring object properties

    const { Id, Description, Number, Datasheet } = articleInfo;
    console.log(Id, Description, Number, Datasheet);
  });
});

// run this code with an html file and see the result in console as console.table() will only work in a browser 
// or if you're using vs code, you can run this code directly
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).